# Generate URL for File

Tags: java

The default output of `File.toURL()` is

```
file:/c:/foo/bar
```

These don't appear to work on windows, and need to be changed to

```
file:///c:/foo/bar
```

Does the format

```
file:/foo/bar
```

work correctly on Unix (I don't have a Unix machine to test on)? Is there a library that can take care of generating a URL from a File that is in the correct format for the current environment?

I've considered using a regex to fix the problem, something like:

```
fileUrl.replaceFirst("^file:/", "file:///")
```

However, this isn't quite right, because it will convert a correct URL like:

```
file:///c:/foo/bar
```

to:

```
file://///c:/foo/bar
```

**Update**

I'm using Java 1.4 and in this version `File.toURL()` is not deprecated and both `File.toURL().toString()` and `File.toURI().toString()` generate the same (incorrect) URL on windows

Comment: `file:/c:/foo/bar` won't work on UNIX... a UNIX machine does not have C: drive

Comment: Indeed, you can just use unix-like paths in Windows. I.e. `/foo/bar`. The root will be on the same disk as the working directory of the Java program.

Comment: What are you trying to do with this URL in string form that is not working?

Comment: @Don then why don't you use `FileReader`?

Comment: @Don, it only accepts a URL, or it only accepts a String referencing the file? If it only accepts a URL, pass it the URL object, don't wory about the `toString()` method. If it accepts a URL object and can't open the file, it has a bug, in that it relies on the toString method of URL to find the file instead of using the URL directly.

Answer (score 12):

The [`File(String)`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html#File%28java.lang.String%29) expects a pathname, not an URL. If you want to construct a `File` based on a `String` which actually represents an URL, then you'll need to convert this `String` back to `URL` first and make use of [`File(URI)`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html#File%28java.net.URI%29) to construct the `File` based on [`URL#toURI()`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/URL.html#toURI%28%29).

```
String urlAsString = "file:/c:/foo/bar";
URL url = new URL(urlAsString);
File file = new File(url.toURI());
```

**Update:** since you're on Java 1.4 and `URL#toURI()` is actually a Java 1.5 method (sorry, overlooked that bit), better use [`URL#getPath()`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/URL.html#getPath%28%29) instead which returns the pathname, so that you can use `File(String)`.

```
String urlAsString = "file:/c:/foo/bar";
URL url = new URL(urlAsString);
File file = new File(url.getPath());
```

Answer (score 6):

The File.toURL() method is deprecated - it is recommended that you use the toURI() method instead.  If you use that instead, does your problem go away?

---

Edit:

I understand: you are using Java 4.  However, your question did not explain what you were trying to do.  If, as you state in the comments, you are attempting to simply read a file, use a [FileReader](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/FileReader.html) to do so (or a [FileInputStream](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/FileInputStream.html) if the file is a binary format).

Comment: +1 - it helps to read the javadocs ... http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html#toURL()

Comment: @Don: I assumed you were using 1.5 or higher - apologies.  I would still attempt to use .toURI(), as it may solve the problem (I seem to remember some problems with .toURL() back when I was using 1.4, but that was a while ago so I could be mistaken)

Comment: Using URI instead of URL doesn't make any difference in Java 1.4

Comment: @Don: What exactly are you trying to do here?  How are you initializing the File object?  Does the File Object actually point to the file you think it does?

Answer (score 1):

What do you actually mean with "Does the format `file:/c:/foo/bar` work correctly on Unix"?

Some examples from Unix.

```
File file = new File("/tmp/foo.txt"); // this file exists
System.out.println(file.toURI()); // "file:/tmp/foo.txt"
```

However, you cannot e.g. do this:

```
File file = new File("file:/tmp/foo.txt");
System.out.println(file.exists()); // false
```

(If you need a `URL` instance, do `file.toURI().toURL()` as the [Javadoc says](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html#toURL%28%29).)

**Edit**: how about the following, does it help?

```
URL url = new URL("file:/tmp/foo.txt");
System.out.println(url.getFile());  // "/tmp/foo.txt"
File file = new File(url.getFile());
System.out.println(file.exists());  // true
```

(Basically very close to BalusC's example which used `new File(url.toURI())`.)

Comment: @Don, If this is not helpful at all, can you please elaborate on what you meant about the format working correctly?

Comment: Using URI instead of URL doesn't make any difference in Java 1.4

Comment: Right. But to be able to answer your question, what are you actually trying to do? I.e., how do you intend to use the format `file:/foo/bar` in code on Unix?