# set an absolute path for a "log4j.properties" file

Tags: java, logging, log4j, apache-commons-logging

I am using apache commons + log4j for my web app.

normally log4j needs a configuration file inside the classpath; but I need to delegate the logging configuration to an external file (I need to deploy a .war in an environment, but the log configurations (max size, position, etc) it's up to a second team.

I have a commons-logging.properties in my classpath

```
org.apache.commons.logging.Log=org.apache.commons.logging.impl.Log4JLogger
# log4j.configuration=/absolute/path/where/external/logs/are/log4j.properties
```

unfortunately, the commented line doesn't work.

Is there a way to set up log4j with an external configuration file?

Answer (score 5):

You can set it as a system property  `log4j.configuration` property .. for example in J2SE app

```
java -Dlog4j.configuration=file:/path/to/log4j.properties myApp
```

Note, that property value must be a URL.

For more read section 'Default Initialization Procedure' in [Log4j manual.](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/manual.html)

It's also possible letting a ServletContextListener set the System properties:

```
import java.util.Enumeration;
import javax.servlet.*;

public class SystemPropertiesHelper implements
        javax.servlet.ServletContextListener {
    private ServletContext context = null;

    public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent event) {
        context = event.getServletContext();
        Enumeration<String> params = context.getInitParameterNames();

        while (params.hasMoreElements()) {
          String param = (String) params.nextElement();
          String value = 
            context.getInitParameter(param);
          if (param.startsWith("customPrefix.")) {
              System.setProperty(param, value);
          }
        }
    }

    public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent event) {
    }
}
```

And then put this into your web.xml (should be possible for context.xml too)

```
<context-param>
        <param-name>customPrefix.property</param-name>
        <param-value>value</param-value>
        <param-type>java.lang.String</param-type>
</context-param>

<listener>
    <listener-class>servletUtils.SystemPropertiesHelper</listener-class>    
</listener>
```

I got this from this listener code from  [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/372686/how-can-i-specify-system-properties-in-tomcat-configuration-on-startup) .

I hope this could help you!

Answer (score 3):

You can use a jvm parameter indicating the configuration file path:

```
-Dlog4j.configuration=absolute path
```

example with an absolute path:

```
java -Dlog4j.configuration="file:/dir1/log4j.properties"
```

Comment: AFAIK this way to set the configuration file it's still using a relative path; can you point me to a document where you've seen using it with an absolute path?

Comment: Wonderful answer. The _file_ prefix seems to be mandatory, at least on a unix OS.

Answer (score 0):

Set the system property log4j.configuration=/abslute/or/relative/path_to_file_name

commons logging only needs to know what logging implementation it's using, the logging implementation it self is configured in whatever way it is always configured in.

This is documented in the [log4j manual.](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/manual.html)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the [Spring Framework](http://projects.spring.io/spring-framework/), you can use the [**`org.springframework.web.util.Log4jConfigListener`**](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/util/Log4jConfigListener.html).

You only need to specify the parameter `log4jConfigLocation` with the file location (using the [URL for File](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2789241/generate-url-for-file)). e.g.:

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>log4jConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>file:/absolute/path/where/external/logs/are/log4j.properties</param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
    <param-name>log4jRefreshInterval</param-name>
    <param-value>1000</param-value>
</context-param>
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.util.Log4jConfigListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

You can specify the `log4jRefreshInterval`, the interval between config file **refresh checks**, in milliseconds.

---

See more in the [*javadoc*](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/util/Log4jWebConfigurer.html) of `org.springframework.web.util.Log4jWebConfigurer`.

Comment: unfortunately in this project I am not using spring :\

Comment: Humm ... You can simply add the required jar file, no need to configure Spring. :)